# GULP: How to combine files AFTER uglify

Tags: gulp, gulp-uglify, gulp-concat

**Scenario**
I need to grab all *.js files in a folder, combine and uglify them. This is what I achieve with:

```
gulp.task('default', function(){
    return gulp.src('resources_folder/*.js')
        .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler: function (error) {
                console.log(error.message);
                this.emit('end');
            }}))
        .pipe(concat('output.js'))
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js/'))
});
```

**But I'm struggling with two things:**

1. AFTER the uglify I would like to concat the result with an other (already minified file). I don't wish to uglify this file again - I want it just to combine with the result.
2. How do I concat the results with a "new line" or a comment please?

**What I want to achieve:**
I have my source fiels in "res" and Im using an external small library (minifeid already) which I would like to include into my output file.

**Something like:**

- put a comment
- grab all sources
- uglify
- put a new line
- put a comment
- put a new line
- combine with the resource library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need two plugins:

[gulp-footer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-footer/)  and [gulp-add-src](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-add-src)

```
 var footer = require('gulp-footer');
 var addsrc = require('gulp-add-src');
```

So after your uglify pipe put something like:

```
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(footer('\n// my comment\n'))
.pipe(addsrc.append('your resource library to append'))
.pipe(concat('new file name here'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('js'))
```

Look at the gulp-footer documentation to see different ways to build up the comment you wish to insert.  You can, for example, read it from a file or variable.

Comment: Sorry for the late naswer - but this worked like a charm! :) Thank you